# Extract variable from tensorflow layers?

Tags: tensorflow

In GANs, I need to separate generation variables from discriminator variables. Is there a way to extract variable from tensorflow layers?

Comment: Just pass the layer to `session.run()` as a parameter or use `.eval()` within an InteractiveSession

Comment: @aseipel Thanks. I mean the tf.Variable instance, not the value of the variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way is using `tf.trainable_variables` or `tf.get_variable` now.

Comment: This works for me. If it doesn't help you, please comment below.